# Running background mode for BLE app using swift stops working

Tags: swift, background, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have medical app that communicates with bluetooth device all the time monitoring heart rate and oxygen. It polls BLE device every second. In swift app I set it as background with following modes: External accessory communication, Uses BLE, Background fetch, Remote notifications, Background processing.

Unfortunately after about an hour gets suspended. I know in Android for example if device in background mode but phone plugged into power then app will never be suspended. Is there some way for the app to be always running? We can tell users to keep it powered or always in foreground.

Comment: External accessory background mode is only for mfi peripherals. Polling is not going to work. Your peripheral needs to use notify/indicate when it has new data.

Comment: I have seen suggestions to check on server if data is not sent then send APN to "wake" up the app. You think it may work?

Comment: What if I set UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true and ask users to keep app in foreground and plugged into power? Will this keep running app indefinitely?

Comment: In theory, yes, but if your app has been working for an hour before stopping, then you may have some other problem.  Normally an app can only execute in the background for about 30 seconds. You haven't shown any code, so there may be some other issue. Also, with your testing did you launch the app from Xcode?  If so, the normal background limits do not apply. You need to test by just launching the app by tapping on the icon.